# bootstrap collaspe not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap collaspe to achieve the collaspe effect. My code is as below

```
<h5 class="text-grey" data-toggle="collaspe" data-target="#color">      
  Filter By Color
</h5>
<div class="collapse in" id ="color">
   TEST
</div>
```

bootstrap js and css are included already.

on document ready I added this

```
$(".collapse").collapse('show');
```

But the h5 is not clickable and my div is not showing as well. Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: bootstrap.js relies on jQuery. Have you it included it on the page prior to the bootstrap reference and the method shown?

Comment: You have misstyped the `data-toggle="collaspe"` it should be `data-toggle="collapse"` see: `http://jsfiddle.net/Asrr3/. Voting to close as too localized...

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your spelling `data-toggle="collaspe"` it should be `"collapse"`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jaBaD/

Just remove `"in"` to have it show up first up. Try this:-

Fiddle with Accordion group http://jsfiddle.net/M9AQh/

```
<h5 class="text-grey" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#color">      
  Filter By Color
</h5>
<div class="collapse in" id ="color">
   TEST
</div>
```